# Intermittent "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" failure

Tags: android

I am trying to create an (android 4.3 and later) app  that starts when the phone boots up.  Using other posts I found on StackOverflow I was able to manage this a few times, but it seems that it is not reliably starting every time I reboot the phone.

My code uses an "ongoing" Notification to prove the app is being started by the OS, but it is not happening every time.  I have rebooted several times and it only seems to get started automatically if the app had been running BEFORE the reboot happened.

I really need this app to be started 100% of the time when the phone boots (regardless of if the app was previously running or not).

How can I make this is always guaranteed to run at system start up?  I can't find any documentation that indicates that the app needs to be running before the phone rebooted in order for this to work.

The method I'm using now is just the standard BroadcastReceiver.onReceive responding to the "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" signal from the OS.  It fires off the notification and then starts an activity.  When it does work it can take up to 2 minutes to start (which is totally fine).

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this issue without installing any other 3rd party apps?

Here's the entire project...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.co.xxxxxxxxxxx.autostart">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name="uk.co.xxxxxxxxxxx.autostart.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and...

```
    package uk.co.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.autostart;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (
                Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())
           )
        {
            NotificationManager nm
                    = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Notification n = new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContentText("In BroadcastReceiver!")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("AutoStart")
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setDefaults(0)
                    .build();

            nm.notify(1, n);

            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("STARTER","BroadcastReceiver");
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and...

```
package uk.co.xxxxxxxxxxx.autostart;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String starter = i.getStringExtra("STARTER");

        if(starter != null) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setText("Started by " + starter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without posting any code is difficult to know what is happening. Some of your broadcast receiver onReceive would help to figure it out. And the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

**Android receiver & RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED & BOOT_COMPLETED failure**

After the obvious stuff:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
and:
            <receiver 
                   android:name="com.twiggwidgets.service.MyScheduleReceiver"
                   android:enabled="true"
                   android:exported="true"
            >
                <intent-filter>
                     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

***Still pulling your hair out ?***

**After Android 3.1**
" the system adds **FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES** to all broadcast intents."
This means you, after 3.1, all apps are stopped on boot.
Why ?. For security reasons.

There are **RULES** to turn the flag off "FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES" .

(1) Your app needs to needs in phone storage, NOT sdcard otherwise the flag set.
 BOOT_COMPLETE is sent before external storage is mounted. if app is installed to external storage it won't receive BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast message.

(2) If the user presses "Force close" from settings OR "unresponsive app" button, the flag is set.

(3) **If the application has never been run, the flag is set (never is relative to current boot state ;O) NEVER means in THIS boot OR you invalidated the flag in the last boot state)**.

Your Reciver will run on boot up (flag not set), if you follow the rules.

**info**

You can register you receiver your in code (it won't help for boot-up).

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.twiggwidgets.service.MyScheduleReceiver");

    MyScheduleReceiver myReceiver = new MyScheduleReceiver();
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

//receiver's (are supposed to) run momentarily, but you knew that.
```

**Tip for testing**

```
Open console/terminal and navigating to /platform-tools (it should be in your path ;O)).
Type adb shell or on linux/mac ./adb shell
In the shell type "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

Like magic your reciever runs !.

Not so easy is it !

see android link :
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will try this as soon as I can (next couple of weeks if I get a chance).  In the meantime if anyone else feels like verifying this solution then please let me know in a comment and I'll mark it as an Answer.  Cheers.

Comment: Check your boot manager (if you have one) "prevent selected apps of running on system startup"

Comment: booting is a NIGHTMARE, .<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" /> is just such a device specific example

Answer (score 0):

You have to also register for `action.REBOOT`:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to make any difference.  Looks like the app still has to be alive before the reboot for it to be started by the OS after.

Comment: @Wossname the app has to be started at least once for the receiver to be registered, but after that it will work even if the app is closed

Comment: If Android's kernel decides to kill the app, then it does not (as far as I can tell) restart the app after reboot.