# AlarmManager does not work when device turned off and then turned on

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have programmed an Alarm Manager which works except when I turn off and then turn on my device. It seem that the pendingIntent is not fired. Do you now why?

Comment: It's been a while since I did Android programming, but isn't that what it's supposed to be? I don't think Alarm Manager has a persistent storage. If you reboot the device, your alarm data will be erased. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ha ok you are probably right! So what can I use to make it work? I mean to make my alarm ring even when I turn off and turn on my device

Comment: OK, you'll have to look it up, but there is some hooks you can use in Android  when an app starts up or when the device boots up. (Or, something like that. Details are a bit hazy now.) So, if that's the case, (1) When you app starts up, repopulate your alarms, and/or (2) IF you can listen to device boot event, you repopulate your alarms when the device is rebooted (even without starting your app). My memory is a bit hazy, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: It has it's problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745396/intermittent-receive-boot-completed-failure/36511244#36511244

Comment: Ha great! Thx a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Broadcast Receiver](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/use-broadcast-receiver-background-services-android/) for background services and attach to your application lifecycles